# Change owner/group of a subdirectory of an fstab-mounted vfat partition

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, fstab, vfat

In all likelihood this is a repeat question, but I seem to be currently experiencing difficulties forming a search query to locate an answer.

I have a vfat partition mounted to `/data` containing all of my media, i.e. `/data/books`, `/data/documents`, `/data/downloads`, `/data/websites`, etc. The `websites` sub-directory is (soft) sym-linked to from `/var/www` such that my Apache2 installation uses the directory as its default `DocumentRoot`. My `fstab` entry is currently set to mount `/data` using my user/user-group (`uid=1000,gid=1000`) such that I can freely make changes to any file without further hassle.

However, I need the `/data/websites` directory to be mounted with the `www-data` user (`uid=33,gid=33`) such that Apache and my web-documents may create, modify, and delete files in the directory. My user is a member of the `www-data` group (`gid=33`) such that I may also make changes to the files in the directory.

`chgrp` and `chown` are out of the question as they simply have no effect on a mounted vfat partition. How can I mount `/data/websites` with a different owner/group (`uid=33,gid=33`) while leaving the rest of the `/data` mount owned by my user (`uid=1000,gid=1000`)?

Comment: Is `/data` and it's subdirectories all one partition, or are `/data/books`, `/data/documents`, etc different partitions?

Comment: Good clarifying question! `/data` corresponds to a singular partition, `/dev/sda5` on my system. All of its sub-directories reside directly upon the partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since FAT does not support notion of filesystem permissions at all, let alone UNIX compatible ones, Linux mounts each file in the filesystem with the same owner and group-owner, as specified in the `mount` command or `fstab`.

A couple options:

- Don't use a vfat partition, use ext2 or ext3 (if this is an Android phone and it's rooted with Cyanogenmod, you might be able to format your card ext2 or ext3 if you look around for a howto)
- This is convoluted but should work.  Install `samba` if it's not already active - create shares according to the folders and permissions you wish to expose, and then mount them using `mount -t cifs \\127.0.0.1\share` etc.  It will be messy and a bit complex but will work OK.

Comment: I'll second the samba solution.  From your comment, I'm guessing you're using `/dev/sda5` as common storage on a multi-boot system, so setting up samba shares, and then "re-mounting" locally to change permissions seems like the best workaround.

Comment: Spot on! Took me a spell to configure everything correctly, but it works like a charm.

And you're right on target @ernie - `/dev/sda5` is indeed my common storage for a multiboot environment.

Many thanks!